# Google Play Console demands I review my app before I release it, but there aren't any additional steps for me to take

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have been racking my brain at this issue for a few hours now and can't for the life of me realize what is wrong with my release.

I'm trying to publish my app to the Google Play Store and have completed all the steps requested of me in the Dashboard besides the last one - "Review and roll out the release".
When I press on this step, I arrive at the Internal Testing page.

[image]

It would seem that this page has no discernible steps for me to take that would advance the release of my app.
When I press the "edit" button, I arrive at the "Create internal testing release" page which has no new details for me to fill in that I haven't already (the image shows that page scrolled all the way down, there aren't any important details above, only the .apk I've uploaded).

[image]

When I finally press the "Review release" button, I arrive at the initial problem.
Under the "Errors, warnings and messages" section, I am informed that I must complete the step which I have tried to complete this whole time: review the app and release it, which is where I began this rant.

[image]

Of course, when I press "Go to dashboard" I end up where this post started.
I would appreciate any help solving this conundrum since I honestly don't understand what is causing this issue.

Comment: Is there a help or support link on this page, where you can ask google employers? They might know their product better than we do.

Comment: I did send a message to Google support, but I haven't received a response yet (and might not in a few days). I hope to receive an answer here more quickly since I need to release this app as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solutions was accessing the Classic Console and checking these two options:

[image]

Comment: Still having this problem and now the Classic Console is no longer available..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to complete some information, in my case I forgot to set the address and some info in **store presence** section. Also, I saw red / blue bullets indicating missing information, check the menu.

[image: console]

Comment: I don't see any details in the "Store Presence" section that I have not filled that are mandatory besides some of the images requested of me to provide for tablets, but the app does not support tablets so that section is irrelevant.